# Issue with Setting Cookies PHP

Tags: php, cookies

Right, I've tried everything I can think of and I'm reaching the end of my tether with this!

Basically I'm trying to set two cookies 'user' and 'usertype'.
Now when I set the cookie user to be the actual username usertype gets set as I intend it too.

However if I get the cookie 'user' set to the id of the user in the table then for some reason the usertype cookie isn't getting set.

The code is pretty simple and is:

```
    setcookie('user',$row['id']);
    setcookie('usertype',$row['type']);
    header('Location:index.php');
```

This way it doesn't set usertype but does set user correctly, however if I simply change it too:

```
    setcookie('user',$row['username']);
    setcookie('usertype',$row['type']);
    header('Location:index.php');
```

Then both cookies are set correctly.

Also for reference a var_dump of $row gives:

```
array (size=6)
  'id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'Test User' (length=9)
  'pass' => string '098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6' (length=32)
  'username' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'email' => string 'test@test.com' (length=13)
  'type' => string '2' (length=1)
```

I just don't understand how the first way only sets the user cookie before redirecting to index.php whereas the second way both cookies get set. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should really specify the domain when storing cookies:

Like this

```
setcookie("cookie_name", $value, time() + (60*60*24*30), '/', '.yourdomain.com');
```

Please, let me know whether it works or not..